# Heroku [WARNING] You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I have an rails 3 (3.0.9) application working on ruby 1.8.7  with the gem devise (1.4.2) on my computer working perfectly.

I tried to push it on heroku and i got the following error message on application load:

```
[WARNING] You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.9 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43292
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:84:in `to'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:79:in `modules'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:88:in `strategies'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise.rb:410:in `block in configure_warden!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise.rb:409:in `each_value'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise.rb:409:in `configure_warden!'
```

The problem comes from devise but i don't know how to fix it.
My model User is correctly defined, and it works on my computer...
Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: did you commit everything before deploying?

Comment: Yes, I did.
Thanks for your help guyz. The spell is correct in my model. Finally i destroyed my app in heroku and then re-pushed it ... and now it works fine. So I dont know why this happened. Probably that one of my commit was not done correctly. 
But thanks !

Comment: check if there is any spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Defined at the top of your user/devise model.

ALso, make sure you run your migrations.

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

In console.

Answer (score 1):

Check inside your users.rb to make sure that you spelled ':database_authenticable' correctly, this seems to be a common problem with this error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticable, :recoverable,
    :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Also, I suggest you take a look here, to see how these people fixed the error.
http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/807f4c6e3475622f