# Devise not working due to this warning: [WARNING] You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I've just added a fresh install of devise to a rails app but it's outputtin a warning on start server start and devise is not working at all:

```
   [WARNING] You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application
```

I 100% do have a model called users.

I've had a look about at others with this issue there is this one ([Heroku [WARNING] You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866371/heroku-warning-you-provided-devise-for-users-but-there-is-no-model-user-defin)) and I've changed the name of ':database_authenticable'. This did not fix it.

Also the devise initializer is set to active record, which is another bug which has this error (require 'devise/orm/active_record'), however this did not fix it either.

Has anyone else has this error, or is there a way I can trace it to get more details? Thanks.

Comment: With regards to the question you posted that you looked at did you try looking or trying the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866588/529640

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help, all of that is in there.

Comment: Does it work in local?

Comment: Also, what context are you seeing this error? Are you trying to log-in with the Devise controllers, or have the forms on other pages?

Comment: What are the options that you pass to `devise_for`?

Comment: @RichPeck does not work in local. The error is a warning when the rails app starts up.

Comment: @gregates the devise for just has :users passed into it.

Comment: Show header of your `User` model here in your post. Also in which place did you do the declaration :devise_for?

Comment: What happens if you comment out `devise_for`, boot up `rails console`, and type `User`?

Comment: Can you post your user model?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have devise_for :users in your routes it will target your user model (singular).  You said the name of your model is users, which could make it not work.

Comment: The model is called User

Answer (score 1):

Check the model is in `app/models/user.rb`, not `users.rb`, and run `ruby -c app/models/user.rb` to do a syntax check.

If User exists and doesn't have a syntax error, it may be failing to load because it's trying to include something that doesn't exist. Comment out the body of the class and see if Devise lets you run `rails console` now.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate devise User
```

Run this above code in `Terminal`, i mean in console so then User model will be  generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Model Naming Convention**

```
Table: users
Class: User
File: /app/models/user.rb
Primary Key: id
Foreign Key: user_id
```

**Controller Naming Convention**

```
Class: UsersController
File: /app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Layout: /app/layouts/users.html.erb
```

**View Naming Convention**

```
Helper: /app/helpers/users_helper.rb
Helper Module: UsersHelper
Views: /app/views/users/… (list.html.erb for example)
```

**Tests Naming Convention**

```
Unit: /test/unit/user_test.rb
Functional: /test/functional/users_controller_test.rb
Fixtures: /test/fixtures/users.yml
```

**Rule:** Model 
The model is named using the class naming convention of unbroken MixedCase and is always the singular of the table name, e.g. table name might be users, the model name would be User. Rails will then look for the class definition in a file called user.rb in the /app/models directory. If the model class name has multiple capitalised words, the table name is assumed to have underscores between these words.

**Note:**

```
so if we say devise_for: users,
we must have a model with name User(user.rb)
```